# PHP - Resizing and saving PNG images. Some are all black

Tags: php, image

I'm resizing and saving PNGs with PHP. The first example doesn't work, the PNG ends up being completely black, but the second example works. The first example doesn't have a transparent background but the second one does. Why doesn't the first example work? Is it a problem with the URL?

```
<?php 
$id = "example";
//$originalFile = "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.v_YT6iKMW6sOOVdCxVYQkwHaE8?pid=ImgDet&rs=1.png"; // Doesn't work
$originalFile = "https://cdn.globalxetfs.com/content/files/210618-China_Materials_02.png"; // Works

list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($originalFile);

$originalImage = @imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);

$newHeight = 255;
$newWidth = 255;

// Create empty canvas
$resizedImage = "";
$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight); // width, height

// Preserve transparency
imagesavealpha($resizedImage, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($resizedImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($resizedImage, 0, 0, $color);

// Resize image
imagecopyresampled(
    $resizedImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    $newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight
);

header('Content-type: image/png');
$imageName = $id;
$imageName = $imageName . ".png";
if(imagepng($resizedImage, "images/" . $imageName)){
    echo "Image uploaded";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "first example" actually is a JPG file (after the server image rendering) , so you need to use
**@imagecreatefromjpeg** instead of @imagecreatefrompng

So the codes (working) should be:

```
<?php 
$id = "example";
$originalFile = "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.v_YT6iKMW6sOOVdCxVYQkwHaE8?pid=ImgDet&rs=1.png"; 
//$originalFile = "https://cdn.globalxetfs.com/content/files/210618-China_Materials_02.png"; 

list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($originalFile);

$originalImage = @imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);

$newHeight = 255;
$newWidth = 255;

// Create empty canvas
$resizedImage = "";
$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight); // width, height

// Preserve transparency
imagesavealpha($resizedImage, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($resizedImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($resizedImage, 0, 0, $color);

// Resize image
imagecopyresampled(
    $resizedImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    $newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight
);

header('Content-type: image/png');
//$imageName = $id;
//$imageName = $imageName . ".png";
//if(imagepng($resizedImage, "images/" . $imageName)){
//    echo "Image uploaded";
//}

        imagepng($resizedImage);
 
?>
```